# exec error code 2

Tags: php, exec, unison

I'm using [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to sync files between two servers.  I'm trying to get PHP to call it after a file is uploaded.

I'm using `exec`, but it's returning an error code of 2.

```
exec("/usr/bin/unison /var/www/html/files ssh://a2//var/www/html/files -batch -prefer newer -times -path uploads", $out, $r);
```

`$out` is a blank array, and `$r` is 2.  What does an error code of 2 mean?

P.S. I ran `php -a` on the command line, and copied and pasted that line, and it worked.  Also, `exec('whoami')` works (and is the same user I was logged in as on the command line).

Comment: I would suggest trying to use http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php in lieu of exec and see if you can read an actual error being output.

Comment: @sberry2A: Dude!  Thanks a lot!  ` Fatal error: Error in creating unison directory /.unison: Permission denied [mkdir(/.unison)]`.  Think I can fix that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!  Using `popen` (thanks @sberry2A) I saw an error.

> Fatal error: Error in creating unison directory /.unison: Permission denied [mkdir(/.unison)]

I ran `chdir('/home/user');`, before running the command, and then saw an error about `HOME` not being set.

So, I added `HOME=/home/user` before the command.  Now it works, and I don't need the `chdir` command either!

```
exec("HOME=/home/user /usr/bin/unison /var/www/html/files ssh://a2//var/www/html/files -batch -prefer newer -times -path uploads", $out, $r);
```